# Can your accepted answer be denoted by proper class name rather then the inline style?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accepted-answer, design

Only noticed this in www.stackoverflow.com at the moment, not sure about meta,superuser,or serverfault.

When using Stylish in Firefox or Chrome Stylist in Chrome there is no way to apply a style to your answer to a question to make it different from the rest of the answers.  Can it be given a class name 'your-answer' perhaps instead of the inline `'style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"` I use a dark theme style and the white background washes out the light text color.

Or does anyone know of a way to apply a CSS style to your accepted answer the way the markup is now?

Comment: Now **this** is a feature request. Nice find, David.

Comment: I have found other things like this I just can't remember what they are at the moment.

Comment: Damn Alzheimer!

Comment: There's a Greasemonkey script that's related: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/65919

Comment: without some ingenious greasemonkey, there would have to be a mass change

Comment: Is there enough energy for a mass change?

Comment: Why would this result in a 'mass' change.  Find the code that set's "style='backgroundcolor: #FFFFFF;" to add the 'your-answer' class along side the 'accepted-answer' class and make the css class and voila, d.o.n.e.  I wonder why it was done the way it is in the first place. I hope I'm not being naive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not seeing any inline background color styles on questions now, so I think we fixed this somewhere along the way.

Comment: So this is actually status-we-might-have-completed.

Comment: @pi look man, I just randomly type things and press F5 then "deploy". What do you want from me?

Comment: What I want from you? Hmmm... Can I choose anything? Will you grant me 3 wishes? Change the number of letters to 2 for @replies so I can see when someone's replying (didn't see that one coming, did you?)

Comment: Have you considered 3.14159?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood I considered pie. Mmmm, pie. Actually, I considered that. Might go back to it. Would I be notified if somebody writes @3.14? Doesnt't the `.` break the @replies?

Comment: Verified. Seems the new questions are okay, the old ones seem to still have an inline (no big deal). #2344098 has the inline whereas new ones don't for example.